# Не могу подключить cocoapods Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, cocoapods

Всем привет! Крч история такая, решил начать изучать Flutter, но столкнулся с первой проблемой, это его подключения).

Пересмотрел куча видосов на ютубе как его подключать и т.д, ничего не получалось потом нашел видос одного индуса и ооо дааа всё получилось, нооо осталось только подключить Cocoapods и тут я обосрался.

Комп у меня Mac apple m1, крч я уже перепробовал всё что, смог найти в инете, официальная документация, видосы, статьи, homebrew, прописывал в терминале всё что реально и нифига не работает... что делать чтобы устранить эту ошибку и скачать это дерьмо))

```
user@MBP-user ~ % flutter doctor            
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.1, on macOS 13.5.1 22G90 darwin-arm64, locale
    ru-UA)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin
        code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install see
      https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for
      instructions.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.81.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.81.0)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
user@MBP-user ~ %
```

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: а что не получилось?
sudo gem install cocoapods  - по идее все, что нужно сделать